# How to convert Python d3blocks chord diagram to react / d3.js frontend

Tags: python, d3.js

Using in Python [the module d3blocks](https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/pages/html/Chord.html), I can create a chord fig:

```
from d3blocks import D3Blocks
d3 = D3Blocks()
df = d3.import_example('energy')
d3_c = d3.chord(df, showfig=False, filepath=None)
```

How can I export this, or even better the javascript model to a way that can be
imported from a react frontent,
or (the best) export a json model and then create it there using d3.js?

I can always save it to an html file and use an iframe to load the whole page using `filepath=...`, serve the file e.g.

```
@router.get("/chord")
async def html_chord():
    file_path = Path(__file__).parent / "static/chord.html"
    return FileResponse(file_path)
```

and then load in an iframe e.g.

```
  <iframe
    title="HTML Preview"
    src={"http://localhost:5000/js/chord"}
    width="100%"
    height="500px"
  ></iframe>
```

But this seems unessecerily convoluted and does not look as beutiful.

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  Looking at `d3blocks`, it is just a helper that spits out html, css and javascript.  With the `filepath` argument you can just dump the entire the chord example into an html file.

Comment: I can, but ideally I don't want to. My goal is to serve some json (?) code that can be passed to my `node.js` react front-end to display the chord (using `d3.js` ?) Saving to disk slows everything down, and using an iframe looks not as good as it should...